# SCRIPT ERROR: @qb-core/server/player.lua:164: attempt to index a nil value (field 'Jobs')

Tags: lua, fivem

So whenever my players spawn in a created character, it seems to work fine. However, when they try to create a new character this issue is happening now and just started.

```
[script:qb-multichara] SCRIPT ERROR: citizen:/scripting/lua/scheduler.lua:739: SCRIPT ERROR: @qb-core/server/player.lua:164: attempt to index a nil value (field 'Jobs')
[script:qb-multichara] > CheckPlayerData (@qb-core/server/player.lua:164)
[script:qb-multichara] > ref (@qb-core/server/player.lua:30)
[script:qb-multichara] > rawExecute (@oxmysql/dist/build.js:26552)
[script:qb-multichara] > processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96)
[script:qb-multichara] 
[script:qb-multichara] > handler (@qb-multicharacter/server/main.lua:107)
[script:qb-multichara] > rawExecute (@oxmysql/dist/build.js:26552)
[script:qb-multichara] > processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96)
```

I don't know what to do here.

I have tried editing the jobs file and making every job on duty true and and even tried removing that line of code. All with the same result.